# Error in implementing RBAC Protected routes in React Router V6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, rbac

I know how to implement protected routes in the React-Router V6, but I wanna go a bit more modular approach. My application is large and I want to separate all the role based routes. For example, there will be an "AdminRoutes" component which would contain all the routes for the admin and then I will add it as a "ProtectedRoute" children.

In short, instead of this:

```
<Routes>
  <Route element={<ProtectedRoutes />}>
    <Route path='/admin' element={<AdminPage />} />
    <Route path='/profile' element={<Profile />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

I want to have this:

```
<Routes>
  <Route element={<ProtectedRoutes />}>
    <AdminRoutes />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

Where the `AdminRoutes` component would return the admin routes like:

```
export function AdminRoutes() {
  return (
    <>
      <Route path='/admin' element={<AdminPage />} />
      <Route path='/profile' element={<Profile />} />
    </>
  )
}
```

Note: the `ProtectedRoutes` component will return children (outlet) or navigate to a different route based on some logic
Currently it's giving me error that "Uncaught Error: All component children of `<Routes>` must be a `<Route>` or `<React.Fragment>`".

Is what I am saying possible? If you know any other better approach than this, I would also wanna know that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Currently it's giving me error that "Uncaught Error: All component children of `<Routes>` must be a `<Route>` or `<React.Fragment>`"

You can't render directly the `Route` component, it ***must*** have either a `Routes` component as its parent, or another `Route` component in the case of nested routes. `AdminRoutes` is neither a `Route` or `React.Fragment` component so it cannot be rendered as a child of `Routes` or `Route`.

In `AdminRoutes` wrap the routes in the `Routes` component so it can correctly render the descendent routes.

```
export function AdminRoutes() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/admin" element={<AdminPage />} />
      <Route path="/profile" element={<Profile />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

> Is what I am saying possible?

Yes, but since you are converting nested routes into descendent routes, the main router needs to render `AdminRoutes` on a route as well, not alone by itself as a child of `Route` (*for the same reason above*).

Render `AdminRoutes` as a routed component on `path="/*"` with the trailing splat so all descendent routes (*e.g. routes rendered in component's `Routes` component*) can also be matched and rendered.

```
<Routes>
  <Route element={<ProtectedRoutes />}>
    <Route path="/*" element={<AdminRoutes />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

### Demo

[image: Edit error-in-implementing-rbac-protected-routes-in-react-router-v6]